# c - how to pass variables from parent process to child, back to parent then to the same child etc, multiple times in c?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, named-pipes

I'm a beginner and I'm still starting to learn about forks and pipes in C.

I'm trying to create a create one parent process and ONE child process that repeatedly pass variables to one another.

parent1 sends a,b --> child1 calculates a+b=c --> parent1 receives c and calculates c * 10000=X, then sends p,q --> child1 calculates p+q=s--> parent 1 receives s, calculates s * 10000=Y --> exit parent and child processes --> system calculates X+Y=Z and returns Z

I know how to keep forking and getting the same parent but different child processes. I basically repeated the code below multiple times opening new pipes and forks (pid1, pid2, pid 3, pid 4 etc. and port1, port2, port 3, port 4 etc.), so the parent was the same, but new children were created.

```
    int port1[2];
    if (pipe(port1) == -1){
        printf("Error occurred with opening first pipe.");
        return 1;
    }
    int pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0){
        close(port1[0]);
        c = a+b;
        if (write(port1[1], &c, sizeof(c)) == -1){
            printf("Error occurred writng to the pipe.");
            return 2;
        }
        close(port1[1]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    else{
        close(port1[1]);
        read(port1[0], &c, sizeof(c));
        X = c * 10000;
        close(port1[0]);
    }
```

but how do I keep passing from parent to the same child several times?

Comment: Please post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that includes all the code necessary for someone helping to compile an exact copy of your example program without obvious errors.

Comment: use queues for example

Comment: You'll need to loop in the child that reads two numbers, calculates the sum and writes the result back to the parent.  Similarly, the parent has a loop that writes two numbers to the child and reads the result back and processes the result.  You have to decide how the parent knows which values to send, that's all.

Comment: This is nitpicky, but I presume you mean you want to pass *values* back and forth, and possibly store them in variables in between, because you cannot pass *variables* themselves at all.  The difference between a value and a variable in which it is stored is not always so important, but there are times when distinguishing is essential.  Best to learn the difference and school yourself to keep it in mind.

Comment: As has been said, fork once. Also, use just one pipe (or socket or other IPC channel). Then, define a protocol for the "dialog" between your two agents.

Comment: @Diego Ferruchelli One pipe won't do since the OP wants bidirectional communication

Comment: @ikegami That depends on the chosen protocol. Anyway, one pipe, two pipes, one named pipe, one domain socket... That's not the point. The point is "don't create a child (and a pipe) for each message".

Comment: @DiegoFerruchelli, it is *extremely* difficult to use a single pipe for bidirectional communication without some other support (such as a semaphore, for example).  I can't think of any features of a communication protocol alone that could make it reliable.  If the "use just one pipe" was not intended to be a focus of your previous comment, then that comment went awry.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In this specific case (please read again the question or my comment on your answer), the protocol is trivial and a single pipe will perfectly do. Do you really want me to write an example of this? I agree that, on more complex situations, it's much easier to use two pipes (mostly for avoiding deadlocks). Anyway, the key point of _this question_ was not "how to use pipes" but "how to handle _several_ sends & receives between a couple of processes". And the key point of all answers was "You don't need to fork and create a new channel _for each message_" (as the OP was doing).

Comment: @DiegoFerruchelli, the problem with using a single pipe for bidirectional communication is that only with some extra help can you *ensure* that each process reads only the data written by the other.  Without any extra scaffolding, it is possible for them to read back data that they wrote themselves.  I would indeed be delighted to entertain your ideas about how to deal with that, but do note that there is a big difference between "it works as I expect under some / typical operating conditions" and "it *always* works as I expect".

Comment: I was about to write "nothing works _always_ as expected", pointing that there are no absolute solutions for all situations. Programming, as we know, is facing _specific_ problems and solving them using available tools (or creating new ones). Of course, there are patterns, usual solutions and better practices (there's nothing wrong with that), but beginners, as eshtabel3asal, should be able to understand the options and choose by themselves. (Anyway, and more strictly speaking, under a given set of conditions, a well written program will _always_ work as expected.)

Answer (score 4):

I anticipate that it will help you a lot (as it often does in general) to separate your code into functions.  In particular, I suggest writing separate functions for the parent side of the communication and the child side.  That will make the code much clearer, and thus easier to write and to read.

The framework would be something like this:

```
void do_child_things(int in_fd, int out_fd) {
    // read parent messages from in_fd and write responses to out_fd ...
}

void do_parent_things(int in_fd, int out_fd) {
    // write child messages to out_fd and read responses from in_fd ...
}

// ...

void some_function(void) {
    // One pipe for each direction
    int parent_to_child[2];
    int child_to_parent[2];

    pipe(parent_to_child);
    pipe(child_to_parent);

    // fork ONCE, since you want only one child
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    // Close unneeded pipe ends and call the appropriate behavior

    // In the child
    close(parent_to_child[1]);
    close(child_to_parent[0]);
    do_child_things(parent_to_child[0], child_to_parent[1]);
    // and terminate
    exit(0);

    // ...

    // In the parent
    close(parent_to_child[0]);
    close(child_to_parent[1]);
    do_parent_things(child_to_parent[0], parent_to_child[1]);
    // and wait for the child to terminate
    int child_status;
    waitpid(child_pid, &child_status, 0);
}
```

You'll have to decide on the specific forms of the messages exchanged, but you have lots of options.  If you don't want to deal with low level `read()`s and `write()`s, then you can use [`fdopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) to get stream interfaces for the pipe ends, with which you can use `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`, `fgets()`, *etc*, which you may be more comfortable with.  In that case, however, do be aware that you will probably need to `fflush()` the output streams after each message.

Comment: I would add, for clarity, that inside `do_parent_things()` and `do_child_things()` there will be a loop (well, one loop per function).

Comment: @DiegoFerruchelli, there certainly *could* be loops inside those functions, but the specific communication pattern described in the question does not appear to require them.

Comment: Actually, at least in the example provided by the OP, the entire dialog will just be: send (a), send (b), receive (c), send (p), send (q), receive (s) (that's from the viewpoint of the parent). I'm not saying that he has to write a loop for this. I'm saying _where_, in your well designed structure, will be the repeated use of the pipes (which, I think. is a key part of the problem).

Answer (score 2):

- Function `call_child(wp,rp,x,y)`:

  1. Write x and y to pipe.
  2. Read result from pipe.
  3. Calculate the modified result.
  4. Return modified result.

1. Create pipes.
2. Fork.
3. If in child,

   1. Close appropriate pipe ends.
   2. Loop,

      1. Read the two values from pipe.
      2. If EOF,

         1. Break out of loop.
      3. Calculate the sum.
      4. Write the result to pipe.
   3. Exit.
4. Close appropriate pipe ends.
5. Call `call_child` with pipes, a and b.
6. Print returned value.
7. Call `call_child` with pipes, p and q.
8. Print returned value.
9. Close remaining pipe ends.
10. Wait for child.

Answer (score 1):

Fork once at the start of your program, then loop within each branch.